# Scroll glue directive error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am trying to use scroll-glue to automatically scrolls to the bottom of message.html page. I tried to add the directive 'luegg.directives' like this.

```
(function(){
'use strict';
 var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen','luegg.directives']);
```

but i'm getting this error

Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module luegg.directives due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'luegg.directives' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

What am I doing wrong? also, is there any other way to auto scroll to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Please add file (scrollglue.js) of 'luegg.directives' after angularjs files in index.html.
Check following inclusion I did for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/higgidy_carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ngtouch/build/ngTouch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-swippy/ng-swippy.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-base64.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollglue.js"></script>
```